# why regex is not working on header to check request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, next.js

I am using regex to add some value to the response header. I am following this documentation

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers

here it is mentioned how to add `Regex Path Matching` it is not working.

For example, I have created a demo application, in which I have written if the request is `/about.css` it adds `my custom header value` in `Edge-Cache-Tag`. **it is working fine**

```js
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/about.css',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Edge-Cache-Tag',
            value: 'my custom header value',
          }
        ],
      },
       {
        source: '/(name-)',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Edge-Cache-Tag',
            value: 'peivarer value',
          }
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

But I want if a request starting from `name-` then it adds `peivarer value` in `Edge-Cache-Tag` .**That is not working.**

in documentation it is written
**To match a regex path you can wrap the regex in parenthesis after a parameter, for example /blog/:slug(\d{1,}) will match /blog/123 but not /blog/abc:**

[image]
here is my code
https://repl.it/@naveennsit/KindlySomberCleaninstall#next.config.js

Comment: To match anything that starts with `name-`, you would just need `source: '/name-*'`

Comment: @codemonkey not working ..!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use that framework, but my understanding of regex is that you need to match beginnings with `^...` so in this case `^name`

Answer (score 0):

Following the example of the docs, this config works:

```js
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/about.css",
        headers: [
          {
            key: "Edge-Cache-Tag",
            value: "my custom header value",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        source: "/:slug(name-[a-zA-Z0-9]*\\.css)",
        headers: [
          {
            key: "Edge-Cache-Tag",
            value: "peivarer value",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

The regex will allow `name-` followed by any character or number, followed by `.css`.